# Configuring Python Logging Correctly with Python Anywhere

Tags: logging, pythonanywhere

I am running a Flask app on PythonAnywhere and everything that is logged is being logged in `/var/log/error.log` This is expected behaviour as everything that is sent to stderr is logged there.

I have it configured to write logs to a FileHandler which it is writing to but it still writes the the error.log as well

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/path/to/log.file', level=logging.INFO)
```

How to I set it so that it will only go to the file and not to stderr?

Answer (score 0):

Errors will always be written to the error log. We have code specifically to do that so that users cannot break the logging and end up not seeing errors.

Comment: The problem is all logs are still appearing in the error.log. So infos are being logged twice, once in my customer logging file and once in the error.log.

Comment: @user7692855 Could you show the code that you use for logging?  I couldn't reproduce this behaviour -- used your `logging.basicConfig` and then called `logging.info('message')`: it appeared only in the file, and was not shown either in the error log, nor in the server log.

Comment: In the views I am using `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and then to actually make the logs `logger.info("User already logged in user_id=%s", current_user.id)`